# Convert string to float in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-conversion

How do I convert a string to a float in Objective-C?

I am trying to multiply a couple of strings I am getting back from JSON:

```
float subTotal = [[[[purchaseOrderItemsJSON objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"Price"] floatValue];

NSLog(@"%@", subTotal);
```

This gives me: `(null)` in the console.  I know that there is a valid string coming out of that array because I am already using it to display its value in a label.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
your_float = [your_string floatValue];
```

**EDIT:**

try this:

```
  NSLog(@"float value is: %f", your_float);
```

Comment: float subTotal = [[[[purchaseOrderItemsJSON objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"Price"] floatValue];    

NSLog(@"%@",subTotal);    
This gives me a (null) on console.  I know there is a string value in there.

Comment: @Max, Can you try to print that string, and paste it here?

Comment: it is: 3399    
and the output ends up being: (null)

Comment: I am a dope - @"%@", I'll leave it at that

Comment: As stated in the documentation, beware that the format is non-localized. In Germany people use a comma as separator, i.e. "1,28" vs. "1.28". floatValue will not work in this case.

Answer (score 18):

The proper way of doing this is

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

float value = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"32.12"].floatValue;
```

Comment: :-) +1 for trying to move the ocean.

Comment: Beware of the locale! With German locale the `value` will be `0.0` as mentioned also by @user111823 in a comment for a previous answer. You need to set `numberFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];`, if you are always expecting `.` as separator.