# How to convert a string to float?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string to float in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191034/convert-string-to-float-in-objective-c)

I'd like to convert a string to a float.

```
/* dict is an NSDictionary to load Preferences */ 
NSString *str = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
```

This is where I got. Now I'd like to convert the string value (in this case `@"32.0f"`) in a float, where it could be processed by my application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
CGFloat strFloat = (CGFloat)[str floatValue];
```

Comment: That's not a floating point number. The floating point primitive has a SINGLE decimal point, like decimal numbers in arithmetics.

Comment: **SORRY for previous example** _consider this one_ ::
it skips digits after point eg: `NSString * str = @"1.12"; CGFloat strFloat = (CGFloat)[str floatValue];` _// 1.0000_

**please follow this one**
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011706/objective-c-convert-long-and-float-to-string/23932420#23932420

Comment: Asmad, I pasted your code into Xcode, ran it, and placed a breakpoint and it works properly - http://i.imgur.com/kUXigNn.png

Comment: Note that this will return 0.0 if the string is not a number. You'll need an additional check to distinguish from a true "0" string input.

Comment: @StanJames sure, that's a given. I'm assuming that the user would perform the appropriate checks that should be performed while using NSStrings.

Comment: This is potentially dangerous because ``CGFloat`` is not guaranteed to be a ``float``, it can also be a ``double``. You may want to do something like the following to be safe: 
`
NSString *numberAsString = @"2.3";
CGFloat numberAsFloat;
if (CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE) {
    numberAsFloat = [numberAsString doubleValue];
} else {
    numberAsFloat = [numberAsString floatValue];
}`

Comment: but also obviously I should never be allowed to comment because I have no clue how to use mini-markdown

Answer (score 6):

Just pass the message `floatValue` to the `NSString` object. [NSString::floatValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)