# Objective-c convert Long and float to String

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I need to convert two numbers to string in Objective-C.

One is a long number and the other is a float.

I searched on the internet for a solution and everyone uses `stringWithFormat:` but I can't make it work.

I try

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", floatValue]
```

for **12345678.1234** and get **"12345678.00000"** as output

and

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", longValue]
```

Can somebody show me how to use stringWithFormat: correctly?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This article discusses how to use various formatting strings to convert numbers/objects into NSString instances:

[String Programming Guide: Formatting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

Which use the formats specified here:

[String Programming Guide: String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

For your float, you'd want:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.6f", floatValue]
```

And for your long:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", longValue] // Use %lu for unsigned longs
```

But honestly, it's sometimes easier to just use the `NSNumber` class:

```
[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:floatValue] stringValue];
[[NSNumber numberWithLong:longValue] stringValue];
```

Comment: That's a good question. The number to the right of the decimal indicates to how many digits the float value should be rounded. For a float 1.123456, the format string %1.2f would return 1.12, and the format string %1.4f would return 1.1234

Answer (score 4):

floatValue has to be a double.  At least this compiles correctly and does what is expected on my machine
Floats can only store about 8 decimal digits and your number **12345678.1234** requires more precision than that, hence only about the 8 most significant digit are stored in a float.

```
double floatValue = 12345678.1234;
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", floatValue];
```

results in

```
2011-11-04 11:40:26.295 Test basic command line[7886:130b] floatValue = 12345678.123400
```

Comment: As I cannot comment Mr craig's answer I shall put it here. using %1.6f does not work alone.  It works fine if float value is a double though.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The format string %1.6f works just fine on float values.

Comment: Well here `float floatValue = 12345678.1234;
 NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.6f", floatValue];` outputs **2011-11-04 12:25:43.133 Test basic command line[15718:707] floatValue = 12345678.000000** on my machine.

Comment: it happens the same on my program

Comment: This has nothing to do with the format specifier. Floats are confusing, but important to understand. A 'float' is a single-precision floating point number, while a double-precision floating point number is (unsurprisingly, and familiarly) called a 'double'. The precision of a single-precision float is approximately 7.225 decimal digits. A good read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format

Comment: I understand the difference between float and double.  And actually, it this the crux of this problem.  Floats are not large enough to hold 12 decimals as a float has 6 bit of exponent and 23 bits for the faction (24 real bits of precision).  But 24 bits can store roughly 7 decimal numbers (7.229 to be exact) which is the first part of the number.  Hence to store  ***12345678.1234*** one has to use a double.  This is well explained on the wikepedia page you provided.  I do think my solution stands as it works in xcode anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **NSNumberFormatter** eg:

```
    NSNumberFormatter * nFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [nFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *num = [nFormatter numberFromString:@"12345678.1234"];
    [nFormatter release];
```